# Layout misshapen when export to PDF in Arc GIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, table, excel, pdf

I want to include an Excel table in my ArcMap Layout which is working fine as long as I won't print to PDF. If I export the map to PDF the table looks like this: 
[image]

There are a lot of weird characters and I have no clue why it looks so different to the original table which is still correct in ArcMap. Does anybody knows a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: In ArcMap>File>Export Map...>Select PDF>Format Tab>Check 'Embed All Document Fonts'

This makes the PDF functional by machines/printers that do not have the fonts used in the source doc. It may be an issue here due the embedded object (Excel) within the map doc.

If that doesn't work, **try changing the font in Excel to Arial.** There are several posts here: https://geonet.esri.com/search.jspa?q=PDF+excel+font

Comment: We like long answers here. Can you expand on why this is the right answer please?

Comment: "Embed all document fonts" is activated but it looks still like above :-(

Comment: Can you post what it should look like?
Have you tried changing the font in the Excel to Arial?
Also, do you have the option to Print to PDF?

Comment: Yes, the font was the problem. I changed it to Arial and it worked. But how is it possible to use a different font without this font distortion?